# ASP.NET MVC 3 Add Custom Header Exception

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, rest, exception, http-headers

I want to add response  header   "Access-Token" >name   "My Custom Value">value

then i am getting this error; `system.platformnotsupportedexception`  why do you think?

```
public abstract class BaseController:Controller 
{ 
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) 
    { 
       base.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Token", AccessTokenValidator.EncryptToken(LoggedInUserId)); 
       base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext); 
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please share your code? how are you adding custom header?

Comment: i shared  code in my question